# How to find all the dependencies of a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database where i have list of tables,procedures,views and triggers.
But i want a query to get all the  dependencies of a table including child tables which are referring the parent table.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The following are the ways we can use to check the dependencies:

Method 1: Using `sp_depends`

```
 sp_depends 'dbo.First'
 GO
```

Method 2: Using `information_schema.routines`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM information_schema.routines ISR
 WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.First', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0
 GO
```

Method 3: Using DMV `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`

```
 SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
 referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
 FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.First', 'OBJECT');
 GO
```

Comment: Let specify the source of this article, Mr. Mala: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/

Comment: Option 3 is the better one, as `sp_depends` is noted in its documentation to be deprecated.

Comment: sp_depends returns wrong results when object is recreated

Comment: Does the sp_depends return just the Store Procedures dependencies?

Answer (score 13):

In SQL Server 2008 there are two new Dynamic Management Functions introduced to keep track of object dependencies: [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql) and [sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql):

*1/ Returning the entities that refer to a given entity:*

```
SELECT
        referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, 
        referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('<TableName>', 'OBJECT')
```

*2/ Returning entities that are referenced by an object:*

```
SELECT
        referenced_schema_name, referenced_entity_name, referenced_minor_name, 
        referenced_class_desc, is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('<StoredProcedureName>', 'OBJECT');
```

Alternatively, you can use **sp_depends**:

```
EXEC sp_depends '<TableName>'
```

Another option is to use a pretty useful tool called [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker) from Red Gate.

Comment: This is the right answer. `sp_depends` is noted in its documentation as deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for both referencing and referenced variations of dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

Besides the methods described in other answers (sp_depends system stored procedure, SQL Server dynamic management functions) you can also view dependencies between SQL Server objects  - from SSMS.

You can use the [View Dependencies option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table) from SSMS. From the **Object Explorer** pane, right click on the object and from the context menu, select the **View Dependencies** option

I myself prefer a 3rd party dependency viewer called [ApexSQL Search](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx). It is a free add-in, which integrates into SSMS and Visual Studio for SQL object and data text search, extended property management, safe object rename, and relationship visualization.

Comment: the dependency viewer has been deprecated out of ApexSQL Search https://blog.apexsql.com/visual-dependency-viewer-feature-deprecated-in-apexsql-search-2018/

Answer (score 11):

Finding all foreign keys

```
SELECT src.name, srcCol.name, dst.name, dstCol.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk
    INNER JOIN sys.columns srcCol ON fk.parent_column_id = srcCol.[column_id] 
        AND fk.parent_object_id = srcCol.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.tables src ON src.[object_id] = fk.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables dst ON dst.[object_id] = fk.[referenced_object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns dstCol ON fk.referenced_column_id = dstCol.[column_id] 
        AND fk.[referenced_object_id] = dstCol.[object_id]
```

Answer (score 6):

Query the sysdepends table:

```
SELECT distinct schema_name(dependentObject.uid) as schema, 
       dependentObject.*
 FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o on d.id = o.id 
INNER JOIN sysobjects dependentObject on d.depid = dependentObject.id
WHERE o.name = 'TableName'
```

A way to look just for views/functions/triggers/procedures that reference the object (or any given text) by name is:

```
SELECT distinct schema_name(so.uid) + '.' + so.name 
  FROM syscomments sc 
 INNER JOIN  sysobjects so on sc.id = so.id 
 WHERE sc.text like '%Name%'
```

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server 2008 or above I use the following query to find all the dependant stored procedures, user defined functions, triggers, etc. for a given table:

```
SELECT 
coalesce(Referenced_server_name+'.','')+ --possible server name if cross-server
coalesce(referenced_database_name+'.','')+ --possible database name if cross-database
coalesce(referenced_schema_name+'.','')+ --likely schema name
coalesce(referenced_entity_name,'') + --very likely entity name
coalesce('.'+col_name(referenced_ID,referenced_minor_id),'')AS [referencing],
coalesce(object_schema_name(Referencing_ID)+'.','')+ --likely schema name
object_name(Referencing_ID)+ --definite entity name
coalesce('.'+col_name(referencing_ID,referencing_minor_id),'') AS [referenced]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id =object_id('Table_name')
ORDER BY [referenced]
```

Answer (score 3):

Method 1: Using sp_depends

```
 sp_depends 'dbo.First'
 GO
```

Method 2 : Using sys.procedures for Stored Procedures

```
select Name from sys.procedures where OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) like '%Any Keyword Name%'
```

'% Any Keyword Name %' is the Search keyword you are looking for

Method 3 : Using sys.views for Views

```
select Name from sys.views where OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) like '%Any Keyword Name%'
```

'% Any Keyword Name %' is the Search keyword you are looking for

Comment: `sp_depends` is noted in its documentation as deprecated. @Mihai Bejenariu's answer is the better one for future-proofing.

Answer (score 3):

The following SQL lists all object dependencies across all databases and servers:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Obj_Dep_Details') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Obj_Dep_Details
END
CREATE TABLE #Obj_Dep_Details
(
   [Database]               nvarchar(128)
  ,[Schema]                 nvarchar(128)
  ,dependent_object         nvarchar(128)
  ,dependent_object_type    nvarchar(60)
  ,referenced_server_name   nvarchar(128)
  ,referenced_database_name nvarchar(128)
  ,referenced_schema_name   nvarchar(128)
  ,referenced_entity_name   nvarchar(128)
  ,referenced_id            int
  ,referenced_object_db     nvarchar(128)
  ,referenced_object_type   nvarchar(60)
  ,referencing_id           int
  ,SchemaDep                nvarchar(128)
)
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB @command1='USE [?];
INSERT INTO #Obj_Dep_Details
SELECT DISTINCT
       DB_NAME()                          AS [Database]
      ,SCHEMA_NAME(od.[schema_id])        AS [Schema]
      ,OBJECT_NAME(d1.referencing_id)     AS dependent_object
      ,od.[type_desc]                     AS dependent_object_type
      ,COALESCE(d1.referenced_server_name, @@SERVERNAME)                AS referenced_server_name
      ,COALESCE(d1.referenced_database_name, DB_NAME())                 AS referenced_database_name
      ,COALESCE(d1.referenced_schema_name, SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id])) AS referenced_schema_name
      ,d1.referenced_entity_name
      ,d1.referenced_id
      ,DB_NAME(ro.parent_object_id)        AS referenced_object_db
      ,ro.[type_desc]                      AS referenced_object_type
      ,d1.referencing_id
      ,SCHEMA_NAME(od.[schema_id])         AS SchemaDep
  FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.all_objects od
    ON d1.referencing_id = od.[object_id]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects ro
    ON d1.referenced_id = ro.[object_id]'

SELECT [Database]                                       AS [Dep_Object_DB]
      ,[Schema]                                         AS [Dep_Object_Schema]
      ,dependent_object                                 AS [Dep_Object_Name]
      ,LOWER(REPLACE(dependent_object_type, '_', ' '))  AS [Dep_Object_Type]
      ,referenced_server_name                           AS [Ref_Object_Server_Name]
      ,referenced_database_name                         AS [Ref_Object_DB]
      ,referenced_schema_name                           AS [Ref_Object_Schema]
      ,referenced_entity_name                           AS [Ref_Object_Name]
      ,referenced_id                                    AS [Ref_Object_ID]
      ,LOWER(REPLACE(referenced_object_type, '_', ' ')) AS [Ref_Object_Type]
      ,referencing_id                                   AS [Dep_Object_ID]
  FROM #Obj_Dep_Details WITH(NOLOCK)
 WHERE referenced_entity_name = 'TableName'
ORDER BY [Dep_Object_DB]
        ,[Dep_Object_Name]
        ,[Ref_Object_Name]
        ,[Ref_Object_DB]
```

[TableName Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ8qG.jpg)

Comment: It's soooo awesome script! Love it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use free tool called Advanced SQL Server Dependencies
http://advancedsqlserverdependencies.codeplex.com/

It supports all database objects (tables, views, etc.) and can find dependencies across multiple databases (in case of synonyms).

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but thought I'd add here.. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/dependencies-and-references-in-sql-server/ talks about different options pros and cons and provides stored proc (It_Depends) that produces tree like result of dependencies very similar to SSMS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is builtin procedure to check dependents:
For an example ,

`Execute sp_depends @objname=N'ssc.RegDash_RoutingAct'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
case when is_caller_dependent=0 then 'NO' ELSE 'Yes'
END AS is_caller_dependent FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('Tablename', 'OBJECT');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code below that lists all objects where a given keyword will be found. Formally speaking it is not a true 'depends on' search but it rather helps locating where a keyword is used in Stored procedures, Views, Triggers and Functions. Useful if you are using dynamic SQL.

```sql
select name, type_desc,create_date,modify_date 
from sys.all_objects o
inner join sys.all_sql_modules m on m.object_id = o.object_id
where definition like '%tableName %'
```