# what's the easiest way to dynamically/programatically drop tables sequentially based on their dependencies?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to drop a set of tables in a database dynamically/programatically.  This will need to be done in sequence to avoid contraint errors. For example, a UserRole table will need to be dropped before a User table. I'm sure this can be done but I'm not sure what the easiest way would be to do this.

Comment: Visual Studio has "schema compare" - I think this works this kind of thing out for you

Comment: @juergen - not sure why my table design would be wrong it uses standard fk's

Comment: @nick I don't think schema compare will dynamically generate scripts for me

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Did you read [this SO post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to drop all related tables to delete the table you want, just delete the Constraints that make the relation between 2 tables. This code will delete the constraints and then drop the table you want.

```
  DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(300);
  DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(300) = 'del';
  DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(300) = 'dbo';
  DECLARE @DelStatement nvarchar (100);

  -- Cursor to generate ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT statements  
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.' + 
  OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) +
                ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
  FROM sys.foreign_keys 
  WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id) = @Schema AND 
            OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = @TableName;

  OPEN cur;
  FETCH cur INTO @Statement;

  -- Drop each found foreign key constraint 
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
   exec(@Statement);
   FETCH cur INTO @Statement;
 END

 CLOSE cur;
 DEALLOCATE cur;
 -- Drop the table
SET @DelStatement = 'drop table '+@Schema+'.'+@TableName
exec(@DelStatement)
```

If you have a list of the tables you want to delete you could put this inside another cursor and it will run for each table.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space  or reserved words like `From`.