# Write sql server query to see how many tables are linked a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Provided there are tables Application, Person, Status, etc...

Status and Person have a link to Application.

Is there a simple sql query that may be written that will give a list of all the tables linked to the Application table (in contrast of using the database diagram).

Application expected results:

- Status
- Person

Please advise on a feasible solution (if any).

Comment: If you want the foreign keys you could run this: EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'

Comment: @Kieran: Solution ideal!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all the dependencies of a table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

Using SP_depends. There are other ways as well like DMV's.

```
sp_depends 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using MSSQL Server then you can run

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'YourTableName'
```

Otherwise you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints
WHERE table_name = <tablename>
```

to establish the foreign key relationships

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check each table name that references to other tables would be this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
                OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
                INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
                    ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
                INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o 
                    ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
```

You can, of course, add more conditions to check for a single table, for example:

```
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) = 'Application'
```

This should give you a result like:

```
TableName  ReferenceTableName
---------- ------------------
Status     Application
Person     Application
```