# Find the stored procedure which uses a particular table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to find if a particular table is used in a stored procedure?

Where I work, there are close to 100 stored procedures and going through each one is not a viable option.

What I need it a list of stored procedures which uses a particular table. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Free tool from redgate can do this: [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/index)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all the dependencies of a table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query maybe of help to you.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM SYSCOMMENTS S
INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS O ON O.Object_Id = S.id
WHERE S.TEXT LIKE '%Table_name%'
    AND O.type = 'P'
```

It can search if a particular word is contained in the stored procedure. If a table name is what you need to find, then it can find it from the stored procedure text. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below SQL. Just replace your table name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   o.name AS Object_Name,
   o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m        
    INNER JOIN  sys.objects o 
     ON m.object_id = o.object_id 
    WHERE o.type='P' and
         m.definition Like '%yourtable%';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%yourtablename%'

Answer (score -1):

Check out sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities. Example:

> SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
>   referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent   FROM
>   sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.t', 'OBJECT');