# SQL Server - Trying to find what is spamming this table

Tags: sql, sql-server

After looking in Azure's QueryPerformanceInsight for a sql database I use daily, I have noticed that a query is being executed **a lot** of times per day (thousands per hour it seems). The query is basically:

```
select * from TableName t where t.Id = id
```

I am trying to hunt down what is executing this query so many times in such a short space of time, and have put this together:

```
select top 1 text.[text], stat.last_execution_time, stat.execution_count, plans.*, stat.*
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans as plans
    join sys.dm_exec_query_stats as stat on plans.plan_handle = stat.plan_handle
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plans.plan_handle) as text
order by stat.execution_count desc
```

This is showing me the query that I am looking for (as the text is the same as shown in Azure Insights) and it also shows how quickly the execution count is rising.
The issue is, I dont know how to find where this query is being executed from! None of the 3 tables I am referencing in the above query have a SessionId column on them so I am unsure where to go from here!

**If anyone has any experience about hunting down a query being spammed against a database over and over, please help!**

Comment: a quick search on the internet revealed [How to know list of users who queried the db and what were the queries they fired?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/13c2d261-d627-4790-a809-0c56a422917d/how-to-know-list-of-users-who-queried-the-db-and-what-were-the-queries-they-fired?forum=transactsql)

Comment: This is an Azure sql database, so I do not have access to trace DMV's such as sys.traces....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server