# Search a group of SQL Server views for tables use

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I am trying to search through a group of views to see if they contain certain tables.

For example: let's say I have about 30 views and I want to see if they use this particular table. How can I go about this?

I can not think about how to do this. Anyone have any ideas that can point me in the correct direction?

We are using SQL Server Management Studio v18

Comment: You could check if the table name(s) appear in the `VIEW`'s [definition in the `sys.sql_modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765323/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-view-definition-from-a-sql-server-using-plain-ado) or [check the table's dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server).

Comment: Using SSMS, right clic on your table, then "View dependencies", you can see all the view, stored procedure depending on the talbe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select this from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%Test%';
```

[MS SQL view](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/fd7018912eb5120acdcc807c40986229/)

Comment: Doesn't really help you if you have a view `SELECT * FROM OtherTableCalledTest` or `SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE SomeCol = 'Test'`. You need `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server maintains a list of object references which you can query in a number of ways for the precise table (or any object required), for example:

```
select o.[Name]
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
join sys.objects o on o.object_id=d.referencing_id and o.type='V'
where referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.tablename');
```