# I need columns and tables that taking reference from primary key of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a primary key column in a table and I need to find the tables that are taking reference from this primary key .

if A is primary key in table 1

column B in table 2 is foreign key taking reference from table 1 column A,

column c in table 3 is foreign key taking reference from table 1 column A,

My answer should return

```
B, table 2

C, table 3
```

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-table-columns-with-their-foreign-keys

Comment: Thank you for your support! @JonasMetzler, but it showing all foreign key columns from the database, but i need columns that taking reference from only one particular table.

Comment: @Vaish That link is one way of doing what you desire. You only need to add the appropriate filter for the table name - something that should be a simply task for someone familiar with tsql. Alternatively you can accomplish the same using SSMS by [finding dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all the dependencies of a table in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005698/how-to-find-all-the-dependencies-of-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Yaar, SMor Thank you for your support, but I am looking for the dependent tables/columns on primary key of a table 1 but I'll get Stored Procedures with this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM
sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN
sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN
sys.tables t
ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE
OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'YourParentTableName'

Comment: This gives the answer for my question.

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to accept it to let others know. Also though, code only answers are typically not that helpful to others who find their way here. Perhaps explaining a bit about what this query is doing and how it's getting the results you wanted with some sample output would be awesome to add in!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).